# Getting compression information of a .tif file in python

Tags: python, compression, tiff

I'm currently writing a script to batch compress a bunch of .tif files in python, however some of them are already compressed and some of them aren't. If you go into the properties of a .tif file you can see what compression, if any, is already applied to the file. How can I check this metadata so I can apply some if/then logic in my script to determine whether a .tif file is compressed?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Python Imaging Library (PIL).

Install it with:

```
pip install pillow
```

(Pillow is an easy-to-install version of PIL. It's useful because PIL is notoriously hard to install)

And then:

```
import PIL
img = PIL.open("image.tif")
compression = img.info["compression"]
```

---

Sample result:

```
>>> img = Image.open('sample.tif')
>>> img
<PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=1 size=1600x2100 at 0x101729EF0>
>>> img.info
{'compression': 'group4', 'dpi': (199, 199)}
```